Power Apps why field month cannot be selected for data grid
I have added a data grid to my canvas and connected to a table with 4 fields year, cost, cost_id and month. Selecting fields for the data grid will permit me to select year, cost, costs_id but not month. Can anyone please tell me how to sort this out.

I do not know why but shutting and re-opening Power Apps has allowed me to select month.
